# Magento 2 Checkout post code (zip code) is not a required filed

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, custom-theme

I want to make the postcode filed a **required** filed in the checkout process. I am sure that by default, this IS required but for some reason, it isn't in my store.

I know there is entry in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` that makes the filed required:

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
     <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
     <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item></item>
</item>
```

But I can't see my theme overwriting this file anywhere but just to be sure I added the original file from vendor to my theme folder. Still no luck.

**How else would I debug this issue?**

*Running on:*

- Magento 2.1.8
- Custom theme "Venustheme/cricket"
- Nginx

Comment: Have you tried cache flush and static content deploy after an update that XML?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found my problem...

Magento 2 has a *built in* feature that allows the user to specify countries for optional post code.

In that feature, you can remove validation for selected countries.

Settings can be found in: **Admin Panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > General > Country options > Zip/Postal Code is Optional for**

You have to un-tick the "Use system value" and un-select the countries that you want the post code to be validated for.

I should have properly looked through configurations rather than jumping straight to the code... I hope someone will find this useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
```

Should be a boolean instead:

```
<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Flush cache and retry?